# Retrieve contact numbers for list of names c# wp8

Tags: c#, linq, xaml, windows-phone-8

EDIT: New question - for clarity & new code see [Selecting contacts in windows phone 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18387249/selecting-contacts-in-windows-phone-8)

Whoever downvoted, thanks a lot. Very constructive.

I have, thanks to MSDN and support on here, got the following code to work, which populates a list of contacts and allows the user to select multiple contacts before saving them to a List object.

However, I would now like to know how to retrieve the contact numbers associated with each name retrieved. I have tried subsequent searches but I feel i have done this wrong and each time it just broke the code.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

```
        private void showContacts(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Contacts cons = new Contacts();

            //Identify the method that runs after the asynchronous search completes.
            cons.SearchCompleted += new EventHandler<ContactsSearchEventArgs>(Contacts_SearchCompleted);

            //Start the asynchronous search.
            cons.SearchAsync(String.Empty, FilterKind.None, "Contacts Test #1");
        }

        void Contacts_SearchCompleted(object sender, ContactsSearchEventArgs e)
        {
            //Do something with the results.
            MessageBox.Show(e.Results.Count().ToString());
            try
            {
                //Bind the results to the user interface.
                ContactResultsData.DataContext = e.Results;
            }
            catch (System.Exception)
            {
                //No results
            }

            if (ContactResultsData.Items.Any())
            {
                ContactResultsLabel.Text = "results";
            }
            else
            {
                ContactResultsLabel.Text = "no results";
            }
        }

        public void saveContacts(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            String strItem;

            List<string> listOfNames = new List<string>(); 

            foreach (Object selecteditem in ContactResultsData.SelectedItems)
            {
                //MessageBox.Show(selecteditem.ToString());
                strItem = selecteditem as String;
                ContactResultsLabel.Text = strItem;

                listOfNames.Add(strItem);

                //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(strItem);
                //MessageBox.Show("Saving " + strItem);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show enough concise code to simplify your problem

Comment: I have removed some superfluous code. What is left 1.) Searches for all contacts 2.) Databinds the results to the XAML UI 3.)Creates a list of names
Hope this helps. Im trying now to get the number associated with each contact. Can you please help??
Thank you :)

Comment: King King, if you are going to comment, please be constructive. I have done my best to reduce the code given to the minimum amount. I have asked my question in as clear terms as I could.

Answer (score 2):

Use var instead of object

I understand your requirement , but i don't understand your code , anyway

I give just for a key like if the `ContactResultsData.SelectedItems` has been your database values,then try this way

```
foreach (var selecteditem in ContactResultsData.SelectedItems)
            {
                //MessageBox.Show(selecteditem.ToString());

                ContactResultsLabel.Text = selecteditem.Name;//The Name is ContactResultsData.SelectedItems return Column Field name
                ContactNumberResult.Text = selecteditem.Number;//The Name is ContactResultsData.SelectedItems return Column Field name

                listOfNames.Add(strItem);

                //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(strItem);
                //MessageBox.Show("Saving " + strItem);
            }
```

Comment: Thanks for this. However, This returns the error 'object does not contain a definition for Name', th same applies for number.

All i am trying to do, is display contacts in a list, show the name, then store the name and number of each selected contact.

Comment: Hello , Thats like a key , That name and Number means ,your columnName

Comment: I'm sorry Ramesh, I must be missing something. I can't figure out what to do with those two lines? The only value to selecteditem seems to be the contact name as shown in the listbox.

Comment: It's okay . The ContactResultsData.SelectedItems is return contact number and contactName? or tell me now the ContactResultsData.SelectedItems whats return ?

Comment: The ContactResultsData.SelectedItems returns only names - these are displayed in a listbox. The selecteditem variable refers to the items selected in the listbox itself - i believe this is where we are hitting problems!!

When I do MessageBox.Show(selecteditem.ToString()); it gives only name

Thank you for your help

Comment: I have tried many things now and can still only get the name of each contact. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Consider this example that's implemented for [Group Contacts](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WacVrH9xpYc) app:

XAML:

```
<HyperlinkButton x:Name="CompanyButton" Content="{Binding ElementName=grid, Path=DataContext.SelectedContact.JobInfo, Converter={StaticResource WorkToTextConverter}}" Visibility="{Binding ElementName=grid, Path=DataContext.SelectedContact.JobInfo, Converter={StaticResource WorkToVisibilityConverter}}" IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=grid, Path=DataContext.SelectedContact.Phones, Converter={StaticResource WorkPhoneExistsConverter}}"/>
<HyperlinkButton x:Name="MobileButton"  Content="Mobile"    Visibility="{Binding ElementName=grid, Path=DataContext.SelectedContact.Phones, Converter={StaticResource MobileToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
<HyperlinkButton x:Name="MessageButton" Content="Message"   Visibility="{Binding ElementName=grid, Path=DataContext.SelectedContact.Phones, Converter={StaticResource MobileToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
<HyperlinkButton x:Name="EmailButton"   Content="Email"     Visibility="{Binding ElementName=grid, Path=DataContext.SelectedContact.Emails, Converter={StaticResource EmailsToVisibilityConverter}}" />
```

.
.

Code:

```
private void Call(object e)
{
    ContactPhone phone = null;

    var kind = e as string;

    switch (kind)
    {
        case "Mobile":
            {
                phone = SelectedContact.Phones.Where(p => p.Kind == ContactPhoneKind.Mobile).FirstOrDefault();
                break;
            }

        case "Work":
            {
                phone = SelectedContact.Phones.Where(p => p.Kind == ContactPhoneKind.Work).FirstOrDefault();
                break;
            }
}
```