# Selecting contacts in windows phone 8

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8

I am trying to add a basic contact list into my app.

So far, the app queries the contact store and displays all in a list.

What I require is a data structure containing the name and number of each contact that the user has selected from the list.

I would love to see your ideas. I am sure it will be something simple I have missed, but I have tried so much I am now very much confused.

Here is the relevant code snippet and accompanying XAML. Thank you so much for your time.
C# UPDATED

```
namespace appNamespace
{
    public partial class contact : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        public class CustomContact
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string Number { get; set; }

            public CustomContact()
            {
            }

            //CTOR that takes in a Contact object and extract the two fields we need (can add more fields)
            public CustomContact(Contact contact)
            {
                Name = contact.DisplayName;
                var number = contact.PhoneNumbers.FirstOrDefault();
                if (number != null)
                    Number = number.PhoneNumber;
                else
                    Number = "";
            }
        }

        public contact()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void showContacts(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Contacts cons = new Contacts();

            //Identify the method that runs after the asynchronous search completes.
            cons.SearchCompleted += new EventHandler<ContactsSearchEventArgs>(Contacts_SearchCompleted);

            //Start the asynchronous search.
            cons.SearchAsync(String.Empty, FilterKind.None, "Contacts Test #1");
        }

        void Contacts_SearchCompleted(object sender, ContactsSearchEventArgs e)
        {
            //Do something with the results.
            MessageBox.Show(e.Results.Count().ToString());
            try
            {
                //Bind the results to the user interface.
                ContactResultsData.DataContext = e.Results;

            }
            catch (System.Exception)
            {
                //No results
            }

            if (ContactResultsData.Items.Any())
            {
                ContactResultsLabel.Text = "results";
            }
            else
            {
                ContactResultsLabel.Text = "no results";
            }
        }

        public void saveContacts(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            List<CustomContact> listOfContacts = new List<CustomContact>();

            listOfContacts = e.Results.Select(x => new CustomContact()
            {
                Number = x.PhoneNumbers.FirstOrDefault() != null ? x.PhoneNumbers.FirstOrDefault().PhoneNumber : "",
                Name = x.DisplayName
            }).ToList();
        }

        private void ContactResultsData_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            Contact contact = ContactResultsData.SelectedItem as Contact;
            if (contact != null)
            {
                CustomContact customContact = new CustomContact(contact);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

XAML

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
            <StackPanel Height="Auto" Width="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,10" >

                <TextBlock Name="ContactResultsLabel" Text="results are loading..." Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextLargeStyle}" TextWrapping="Wrap" />

                <ListBox Name="ContactResultsData" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Height="436" Margin="12,0" SelectionMode="Multiple" >
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Name="ContactResults" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeMedium}" Text="{Binding Path=DisplayName, Mode=OneWay}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
            </StackPanel>
            <Button x:Name="showButton" Content="Show Contacts" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="218" Height="90" Margin="0,531,0,0" Click="showContacts"/>
            <Button x:Name="saveButton" Content="Save Contacts" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="238,531,0,0" Width="218" Height="90" Click="saveContacts"/>
        </Grid>
```

Comment: Assuming you want something smaller than the `Contact` class that is returned, can't you just create a custom Contact class with the fields you want (e.g. Name, Number etc..)?

Comment: Ah okay, that's an interesting idea. How do I actually get the number associated with the name that is chosen though? This is the part giving me a headache!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create your class

```
public class CustomContact
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string Number { get; set; }

   public CustomContact()
    {
    }

    //CTOR that takes in a Contact object and extract the two fields we need (can add more fields)
    public CustomContact(Contact contact)
    {
        DisplayName = contact.DisplayName;
        var number = contact.PhoneNumbers.FirstOrDefault();
        if(number != null)
            Number = number.PhoneNumber;
        else
            Number = "";
    }
}
```

And then iterate through the results and add them to your class

```
List<CustomContact> listOfContacts = new List<CustomContact>();
foreach (var c in e.Results)
{
    CustomContact contact  = new CustomContact();
    contact.DisplayName = c.DisplayName;
    var number = c.PhoneNumbers.FirstOrDefault(); //change this to whatever number you want
    if (number != null)
        contact.Number = number.PhoneNumber;
    else
        contact.Number = "";

    listOfContacts.Add(contact);
}
ContactResultsData.DataContext = listOfContacts;
```

You could shorten the `foreach` loop above into a single LINQ query

```
listOfContacts = e.Results.Select(x => new CustomContact() 
                                  { 
                                     Number = x.PhoneNumbers.FirstOrDefault() != null ? x.PhoneNumbers.FirstOrDefault().PhoneNumber : "", 
                                     DisplayName = x.DisplayName 
                                  }).ToList();
```

**Update based on comment.**

Assuming you don't use the above method, the ListBox will be filled with `Contact` objects (and not our `CustomContact` objects). We therefore convert the selected item into a `Contact` object and use the overloaded constructor that takes in a `Contact` object to create the `CustomContact` object that we want.

```
private void ContactResultsData_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Contact contact = ContactResultsData.SelectedItem as Contact;
    if (contact != null)
    {
        CustomContact customContact = new CustomContact(contact);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Will try this in a moment, but it looks great. Thanks!!

Comment: You're welcome :) Let me know if there's something in there that you don't understand.

Comment: Tried this - works great thanks. Except for one thing - this seems to add the results from the Contact Async Query to the custom class...not the selected items from the listBox XAML element.

How could I go about storing the phone numbers associated with the selected contacts?? Thank you for your help so far. Again, im probably overlooking something simple, but Ive spent all day on this problem to no avail!

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood, I thought you wanted to bind to the `CustomContact` objects. Check my updated answer (and note that the class has also been updated with a new constructor).

Comment: Thank you very much. I really appreciate your help with this, however, I am really struggling to get to grips with this. Please bear with me, you've been a great help so far!!

Please see my updated code to see what I've done so far. I don't know where I'm going wrong, but in the saveContacts method I am getting the error 'Results' is not found in 'e'.

Thank you once again.

Comment: That's because `saveContacts` only takes in a `RoutedEventArgs` which doesn't have a `Results` property. It worked for `Contacts_SearchCompleted` because `e` was of type `ContactsSearchEventArgs` (which does have a `Results` property). I think you're trying to get the selected items from the listbox, so you can use `ContactResultsData.SelectedItems` instead of `e.Results`.

Comment: That's exactly the issue. thank you very much, especially for being so patient...can't tell you how much I appreciate your help. I changed `e.Results` to `ContactResultsData.SelectedItems` but now I get an error stating `System.Collections.IList does not contain a definition for 'Select'`

May I ask for your help one final time?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36051/discussion-between-user1456776-and-keyboardp)

Comment: I am using your post and its good, but its not show me all contacts and when I insert break point at this line `ContactResultsData.DataContext = listOfContacts;` and `listOfContacts` have an array but not show array in the listview ``ContactResultsData`. Kindly help me.